# Merge arrylists and save as arraylist with in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 3 Array List and i want to merge those Array List into one arraylist
like, 
merge first object of all arraylist into one arraylist and put that arraylist as a first object of new Arraylist
merge second object of all arraylist into one arraylist and put that arraylist as a second object of new Arraylist
like so that i need output
is there any possibility to do this

Comment: Please take a research and test, if you have any error, come back here please. Gook luck

Comment: while am trying to give an example it was unable to post, giving some errors. that's why i just said in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is basically a [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) function.

Here is an example using `Iterator`, that can handle any number of lists, and each list can be different size.

```
List<List<Integer>> input = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4),
                                          Arrays.asList(5,6,7),
                                          Arrays.asList(8,9,10,11,12));

Iterator<Integer>[] iters = new Iterator[input.size()];
int i = 0;
for (List<Integer> list : input)
    iters[i++] = list.iterator();

List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    List<Integer> sublist = new ArrayList<>(iters.length);
    for (Iterator<Integer> iter : iters)
        if (iter.hasNext())
            sublist.add(iter.next());
    if (sublist.isEmpty())
        break;
    output.add(sublist);
}

System.out.println("Input:  " + input);
System.out.println("Output: " + output);
```

*Output*

```
Input:  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
Output: [[1, 5, 8], [2, 6, 9], [3, 7, 10], [4, 11], [12]]
```

Comment: but, i want <String> arrayList
Please suggest me

Comment: If you want `String` instead of `Integer`, replace `Integer` with `String`. If not that, then I have no clue what you are asking. Maybe clarifying the question might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, list1, list2, and list3 are the three lists you already have

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> oneBigList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList[] groups = new ArrayList[list1.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++)
{
    groups[i] = new ArrayList();
    groups[i].add(list1.get(i);
    groups[i].add(list2.get(i);
    groups[i].add(list3.get(i);

    oneBigList.add(groups[i]);
}
```

Now oneBigList would be an array of arrays; each array containing the 3 elements of the given index (i) from the 3 previous ArrayLists

Comment: This is one of the most confusing things I have ever seen. Why are you jumbling up arrays and array lists like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach assuming the `ArrayList`s are not of the same size.

You have three ArrayList, for example:

```
List<Integer> arr1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
List<Integer> arr2 = Arrays.asList(5,6,7);
List<Integer> arr3 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

First you need to find the one with the more number of values, since the `ArrayList` with the result will have that length:

```
int maxLength = Math.max(arr1.size(), Math.max(arr2.size(), arr3.size()));
List<List<Integer>> finalArrayList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(maxLength);
```

Then, iterating in one `for` block all the lists, get the values of the index in turn and add them to the final `ArrayList` using a temporal `ArrayList` and checking if the index is within the size of the `ArrayList`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
     List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     if(i < arr1.size()) {
         temp.add(arr1.get(i));
     }
     if(i < arr2.size()) {
         temp.add(arr2.get(i));
     }
     if(i < arr3.size()) {
         temp.add(arr3.get(i));
     }

     finalArrayList.add(temp);
 }
```

After that, `finalArrayList` will have:

```
[[1, 5, 1], [2, 6, 2], [3, 7, 3], [4, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: Your example might be clearer if you use all different numbers, e.g. `arr2 = [5,6,7]`.

Comment: Since you just calculated `maxLength`, you might as well give it in `new ArrayList<>(maxLength)`.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(maxLength)` is not really necessary since `ArrayList` size is dynamic, but I changed it anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: what happen if we had N number of arraylist? how to take max length from those n number of arraylist? i am getting results from a database. sometimes it has more than 3 arraylists. please suggest me

Comment: An easy way would be to iterate all your ArraLists keeping in a variable the max length, comparing the lenght with the previous one. See this for many ways to do it: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/maximum-value-in-array/